# How to create a batch file to zip files inside multiple folders?

Tags: batch, zip

Please help me to create zip inside multiple folders as follows using batch.

operating system: windows 10 and 7 zip is installed on machine.
sorry, i dont have any previous code.

Original Directory:

Spanish folder

```
MC.indd
MC.idml
MC_LR.pdf
```

India folder

```
MC.indd
MC.idml
MC_LR.pdf
```

Should become:

Spanish folder

```
MC.indd
MC.idml
MC_LR.pdf
MC.zip
```

India folder

```
MC.indd
MC.idml
MC_LR.pdf
MC.zip
```

The MC.zip should contain MC.idml and MC.pdf files.

There are total 30 countries language folders. once done all idml files should be deleted from every country folder.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679905/edit) your question and add the following: 1) your operating system 2) the batch file you are currently using to resolve the issue 3) info on what the actual result of running your batch file is. You will be helped to get it working, but nobody will write one for you.

Comment: What do you want to use WinRar, 7zip or Powershell?

Comment: WIndows operating system, and 7zip is installed on my machine

Comment: Cross Posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471519/zip-specific-files-that-are-located-in-subdirectories). User also has [previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387518/how-to-zip-multiple-folders-using-batch-script) they could adapt to solve there question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an updated answer form my previous answer but now:

1. The zip file gets the same name as the *.idml file for each folder
2. Only copy *.pdf files that have *LR* in the name
3. Delete all *.idml files in the end

You have to drag the main folder (where the indian, english folders are...) to the batch file.

In the set Seven= part you have to specify the path to the command version of 7zip "7z.exe"...

```
@echo off

:: Set path to 7z.exe here:
set Seven=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

IF /i exist "%~1" (set "Folder=%~1") else exit

pushd "%Folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do call :CreateZip "%%~a"

del /q /s "%Folder%\*.idml"
exit

:CreateZip
set IDMLName=
pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.idml') do set "IDMLName=%%~na"
IF "%IDMLName%"=="" set "IDMLName=MC"
"%Seven%" a -tzip "%IDMLName%.zip" "*.idml" "*LR*.pdf"
popd
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Comment: it works like magic, thank u. 
but there are two pdfs in my folder MC_LR.pdf and MC_HR.pdf and so only MC_LR.pdf should be in zip. also file naming keeps changing its not always "MC" so i have editied the code. "%Seven%" a -tzip "mc.zip" "*.idml" "*.pdf" but here noth pdfs get in zip and filenaming get MC. file naming should of .idml file. sorry for not notifying this previosuly.

Comment: So about the MC_LR.pdf you say it is not always "MC" in the front but what about the "LR" is that fixed? If yes you could use: https://i.imgur.com/BREHNG0.png

Comment: The name of the zip file should be the same as the *.idml file? Is there always only one *.idml in each folder and if not what should be name of the zip?

Comment: LR pdf issue solved, thanks. i have rewrite the code as per ur shared image.
yes there will be always 1 idml in every folder and naming of zip should be as per idml.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer...